# MODULE_NOT_FOUND error when using Prisma with ModuleAliases

Tags: typescript, prisma, module-alias

I wanted to add a module alias for `prisma.ts`, to use

`import prisma from '@prisma'`

instead of a relative path import.

I tried it by adding this to the `tsconfig.json`:

```
"paths": {
    "@services/*": ["lib/services/*"],
    "@prisma": ["lib/db/prisma"]
},
```

and adding this to the `package.json`:

```
"_moduleAliases": {
    "@services": "dist/lib/services",
    "@prisma": "dist/lib/db/prisma"
},
```

The service part works perfectly and the IDE finds the prisma as well, but after compiling I've got a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error

> Error when loading '/opt/bot/dist/listeners/api/match.js': Error: Cannot find module '/opt/bot/dist/lib/db/prisma/client'

But if I remove the alias and import it with it's relative path the compiler finds it easily.

What could be the problem with the aliases?